# Early Exit from Fast Enumerate Loop?

Tags: objective-c, fast-enumeration

When using fast enumeration, is there a way to exit early, i.e. before going through every element in the array?

```
    for (element in myArray)
    {
        //is there a way to exit before running through every element in myArray?
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`break;` will exit any `for`, `while`, or `do` loop.

For example:

```
for (element in myArray)
{
     if (someExitCondition)
     {
         break; /* leave now */
     }
}
```

Read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt88dxx6(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Better way to do is, use blocks

```
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
stop = YES // To break the loop }];
```

Comment: What advantages come with this approach?

Comment: In the original post they were already using a standard for loop, so I see no reason to change it to use blocks when there isn't a need.

Comment: I am not saying he/she should use this but according to apple enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock are faster than regular for loop and Fast Enumeration.